# thumbnails are cropping automatically in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, image

I use this code for show pages thumbnails

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array('class' => 'img-responsive')); ?>
```

but images crop from 1290px*400px to 150px*150px

I add the following code to functions.php but problem not resolved

```
function remove_image_size_attributes( $html ) {
    return preg_replace( '/(width|height)="\d*"/', '', $html );
}

// Remove image size attributes from post thumbnails
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'remove_image_size_attributes' );

// Remove image size attributes from images added to a WordPress post
add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'remove_image_size_attributes' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You have :

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array('class' => 'img-responsive')); ?>
```

So your image size,  takes thumbnail size. For full image size,  Try to give:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'img-responsive')); ?>
```

Or you can also show images like this

```
<?php $url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post_id, 'full' ); ?>

<img src="<?php echo $url;" ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array('class' => 'img-responsive')); ?>
```

to

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'img-responsive')); ?>
```

Or you can also show images like this

```
<?php $url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post_id, 'full' ); ?>

<img src="<?php echo $url;" ?>
```